# Help manipulating simple cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im having difficulty manipulating the left hand side of the equation to get the right hand side. That is starting with only x^3-3x how can I derive the equivalent form on the RHS?

$$x^3-3x = \frac{x^3+3x(x+2)(x-2)}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing

$$x^3 - 3x = \frac{4x^3 - 12 x}{4} = \frac{x^3 + \Big(3x^3 - 12x\Big)}{4}$$

Now factor.